# Common practice cancel async methods in .NET Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, blazor

We are currently setting up a SPA in blazor and we use the NavManager to navigate between pages.
Let's say we have two pages employees and customers.
Both Pages contain a simple table with data inside, this data comes from a database.

If a user navigates to the employees page, the application will load asynchronously all data from the database like this:

```
var employees = await Database.Instance.Employee.GetAllActive();
```

Now there is quite some work which needs to be done, to get the whole employee list, so it takes some time to load all data.

If the user now switches to the customer page, before all employees are loaded, it will load the employees until it's finished. After that the Customers will be loaded.

So now the user needs to wait until all employees are loaded and after that the customers will be loaded.

Now here is my question:
What would be the best way to prevent something like this?
Using CancellationTokens? Or is there anything else we could use?

Comment: The best option is to *not* load all employees. Load only the data that really needs to be shown. Either use paging explicitly or scroll virtualization to load new rows as needed. Cancellation on navigation is explained in the docs but that just covers up the real problem. All grid components support virtualization in one way or another, including Blazor's own [QuickGrid](https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/virtualizing/)

Comment: `CancellationToken` can be passed through from ASP.Net requests all the way through to SqlClient. Be careful: you don't want to cancel `Post` requests which make changes otherwise you won't know if it's been committed. But yeah you should probably rethink what you're doing anyway.

Comment: In addition to the above relevant comments, are you using a DbContextFactory?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If i only load the necessary entries, it still needs some time. So it does not solve my problem...

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis i use create a api request to get my data. Nothing directly with the database.

Comment: It does solve the problem, because loading 50 rows is so fast it won't be noticed. And even if you navigate away, it won't matter. I already explained how cancellation on navigation works too - trigger it in the component's Dispose

Comment: `create a api request to get my data.` what does that mean? An HTTP or gRPC API? Or an intermediate service that still calls a database? That matters a *lot* and may change the question completely. If you make an HTTP call, it's not the loading that needs cancellation. You need to tell the remote server to cancel the operation. This is only possible if that server has such an API. Otherwise the only thing you can do is stop waiting for a response. You can do that with `.WaitAsync(cts.Tolen)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we use a HttpClient, we tried to transfer a ```CancellationToken```, but somehow we can't always catch the TaskCanceledException...

Comment: The last statement is unclear because as I explained, HTTP has no cancellations *at all*, no matter what language, OS or stack is used. Once the server receives a request it doesn't check for additional incoming data. A CancellationToken isn't a data object anyway - there's nothing to transfer. If you want to tell a remote server to cancel an operation, you have to cancel the appropriate API, eg make an HTTP POST to `Jobs/347/Cancel`.

Comment: If you use a paging approach on the other hand, cancelling means not requesting the next page of results. It could be as simple as `if(token.IsCancellationRequested) break;` in the paging loop.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your help! But we found out, it is only slow, if we execute the application in debug mode. If we execute the release build it's more than 20 times faster.

Comment: In my opinion, the right way is to have a global cancelation token for blazor page (spa) and make page to implement `IDisposable`.  Then, invoke cancel over the global page token on page `Dispose`. Be sure to send this global token to all page async operations.